# Wrapping an img tag in an a tag with the src attribute as the href

Tags: php, regex

I need help turning something like:

```
<img class="coup-pic" src="http://example.com/img/pic.jg" alt="" />
```

into:

```
<a href="http://example.com/img/pic.jg"><img class="coup-pic" src="http://example.com/img/pic.jg" alt="" /></a>
```

I need to be able to dynamically search for a string like the one above using PHP and wrap it in an a tag with the src attribute used as the a tag. I think I'll need to use preg_replace, but I do not know the right regex to use.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it an option to use JavaScript (jQuery specifically) to do this? If so, it's a pretty simple exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need to do this with PHP. I've inherited a mess of a site and I'm trying to cleanup some content stored in a database automatically as opposed to doing it by hand.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to permanently change some old HTML in their database, which he would otherwise have to do by hand, so he's putting together a quick PHP script to make it easier for him. That's why he doesn't want JavaScript.

Comment: You're trying to do a strange thing here... if the class is allways coup-pic and alt is allways "" then this would be possible in php, can you tell me if it is or not?

Comment: Believe me...I know this is odd. I'm quite frustrated about the situation. I'm trying to cleanup old data. The img tag will always look exactly as it does here, with only the src attribute content changing. I think this can be done with a preg_replace, but I just don't know regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not currently somewhere where I can test this, but give this a try:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>)/i', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $html);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does the trick. You have handled this situation with great aplomb.

Comment: Glad to help! And what a word (aplomb)!  I need to add that to my vocabulary.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, I would use: `[^>]` instead of: `[^/]` and leave off the: `/` in the closing: `/>` sequence. (just in case there is an attribute value containing a: `/`)

Comment: This will fail to match if the `<img>` has a separate closing tag (`</img>`), but since @Sardine said in the original post that every one is in the exact same, self-closing format, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hey all...thanks for more advice on this! I think I'll implement the changes just to be safe! I have the utmost respect for those who know regex. I fancy myself a decent PHP programmer, but cannot seem to wrap my head around regex.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

`preg_replace('/\<img class="([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)" src="([A-Za-z0-9\-\.\:\/]*)" alt=""\/\>/','<a href="\\2"><img class="\\1" src="\\2" alt=""/></a>',$string);`